# Unchecking all layers in ArcGIS Pro legend

Tags: arcgis-pro, layers, legend

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.8, I have a "Master" aprx file that has ~100 layers. When I insert a legend, the contents pane shows all 100 layers, most being ones that are not even activated on the map. It is a mess to sort through.

Is there a way to uncheck all layers, and then check only the layers that are activated?

Answer (score 2):

In the Contents pane, if you use the Ctrl key to click on any currently ticked layer then all layers at that grouping level will be turned off.

Conversely, if you use the Ctrl key to click on any currently unticked layer then all layers at that grouping level will be turned on.

An alternative to this is to select the first layer, scroll to the bottom of the TOC, hold SHIFT key down and then select the very last layer, doing this allows you to select all your layers. Finally right click on any selected layer and choose **Turn Off**.